# Empty variable when extracting 'a' tags using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, list-comprehension

I need to extract all links from the dump:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

index = requests.get('https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html').text
soup_index = BeautifulSoup(index, 'html.parser')
dumps = [a['href'] for a in soup_index.find_all('a')
        if a.has_attr('href') and a.text[:-1].isdigit()]
```

But I get an empty dump variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because there is no `a.text` which has a digit as its last character.

Comment: @JackFleeting how do I work around it? Here is one of the examples '<a href="zhwiki/20200701">zhwiki</a>'

Comment: Yes, many `<a>` nodes have text, but the text doesn't end with a digit like `.isdigit()` requires. So there's no way to work around that; you can remove the condition and print the text, if that's what you need.

Comment: Also, what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting I am trying to extract the links

Comment: Just the links? Then you don't care about the text?

Comment: @JackFleeting my apologies, you are correct - both links and text

Comment: Ok, but as I said in the first comment - there is no `a.text` with a digit as its last character; if you want the whole text, it's simpler.

Comment: @JackFleeting so, remove isdigit() ?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
targets = soup_index.find_all('a',href=True)
for target in targets:
    print(target,target.text)
```

Output:

```
<a href="angwikibooks/20200701">angwikibooks</a> angwikibooks
<a href="huwikisource/20200701">huwikisource</a> huwikisource
<a href="cswikiquote/20200701">cswikiquote</a> cswikiquote
<a href="cawikibooks/20200701">cawikibooks</a> cawikibooks
```

etc.